# Security Rules: checking for null auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

For each security rule, is it necessary to always check auth !== null? It seems redundant to have to do this for every child rule.

I checked Firebase's own Firechat security rules and the enforcement is not consistent at all. There are rules that use auth.uid but do not check for null auth.

What happens if auth is null and auth.uid is used in the rule?

And what is the recommended practice regarding checking auth !== null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check `auth !== null` if you want the data restricted to any authenticated user.

You need to check for `auth.uid == $uid` when you want the data restricted to the currently authenticated user. You don't need to check for `auth == null && auth.uid != $uid` because `auth.uid == $uid` will evaluate to false if the `auth` variable is null. But you can still include both to be thorough.

So essentially, `auth != null` is restricts the data to any authenticated user, and `auth.uid != null` restricts to the single currently authenticated user.

*Now for some extra curricular information.*

**Use the [Bolt compiler](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/quickstart.html) to simplify common rules.**

Security Rules are flexible, but they don't have much convenience for reproducing common rules. For that, you can use the [**Bolt compiler**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/quickstart.html).

[The Bolt compiler](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/quickstart.html) allows you to create types and assign them to paths in your Firebase database. These types act as schema. You can also create functions that abstract common rules.

I [wrote a blog post on securing user data with Bolt](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-11-12-security-rules-bolt-user-data.html). It goes through what you need to know to keep user data secured with types and functions in Bolt.

```
isCurrentUser(uid) = auth != null && auth.uid == uid;
isAuthenticated() = auth != null

path /users/$uid {
  read() = isAuthenticated() // any authenticated user can read 
  write() = isCurrentUser($uid); 
}
```

In the example above we reuse the `isCurrentUser()` function three separate times. This will make changes moving forward much easier to deal with.